# Implementing sbrk for a custom allocator in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I took on a for-fun task of creating a memory allocator which uses process memory rather than making a bunch of system calls to the operating system. The task was: implement my own `malloc()` and `free()` functions which are limited to a pool (stack array) of 20000 bytes. I already had my own malloc and free implementations which used the `sbrk()` in unistd.h, but I realized the difference here would be that I need to re-create an sbrk that instead of getting memory from the OS, gets memory from my array. I had no experience doing this and was quite frankly pretty unfamiliar with how `sbrk()` worked internally. Even more, I still don't fully understand unistd's `sbrk()` integer pointer param. Nevertheless, I came up with a way to imitate the functionality below:

```
#define MEMORY_CAPACITY 20000
//NOTE: These are GLOBAL variables below
char global_mem[MEMORY_CAPACITY] = {0};
void *p_break = &global_mem;
void* mov_sbrk(int increment)
{
    void *final_address = (char*) global_mem + (MEMORY_CAPACITY-1);
    void *original = p_break;
    if(increment == 0)
    {
        return p_break;
    }
    if(((char*)p_break + increment) < (char*)global_mem)
    {
        ERR("mov_sbrk: Cannot move to address prior to start of memory.");
        return (void*) -1;
    }
    if(((char*)p_break + increment) > (char*)final_address)
    {
        ERR("You've run out of memory!");
        return (void*) -1;
    }
    p_break = (void*) ((char*)p_break + increment);
    return original;

}
```

Note that ERR is just a macro for `fprintf(stderr, msg)`. Please critique this implementation and let me know if I am missing anything. I've performed some tests with my allocator and so far, it performs as expected. The difference though is that I used a int because a int ptr like the "official" `sbrk()` uses as a parameter didn't make sense to me since it would force increments of the architecture's integer size rather than byte-by-byte.

Comment: Instead of explaining `ERR`, you should just include its definition in your program.  Note that it then requires `<stdio.h>`, too, to declare `fprintf()`.

Comment: There's a lot of casts there. Not a good sign

Comment: What is the BSD license of the code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Interface: consider accepting larger types than `int`.  The Linux man page says:

> Various systems use various types for the argument of `sbrk()`.  Common are `int`, `ssize_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `intptr_t`.

`ptrdiff_t` seems like the most appropriate choice.  Of course, it doesn't really matter with this implementation, as the capacity is less than 32768, and so even a minimal `INT_MAX` allocation will fail.

---

> ```
> if(((char*)p_break + increment) < (char*)global_mem)
> ```

Since we have no guarantee that `p_break + increment` won't overflow, we should re-write that as:

```
if (increment < global_mem - (char*)p_break)
```

We know that `global_mem - p_break` can't overflow, as they are pointers into the same object.

Similarly,

> ```
> if(((char*)p_break + increment) > (char*)final_address)
> ```

should be rewritten as

```
if (increment > (char*)final_address - (char*)p_break)
```

---

We can avoid all the casts here by using `char*` pointers rather than `void*` - only the public interface needs the `void*`.

---

I hope the `ERR` macro is compiled out in non-debug builds - users certainly won't want or expect output from `sbrk`.

The error paths should set `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <errno.h>

#define MEMORY_CAPACITY 20000

void *mov_sbrk(int increment)
{
    static char global_mem[MEMORY_CAPACITY] = {0};
    static char *p_break = global_mem;

    char *const limit = global_mem + MEMORY_CAPACITY;
    char *const original = p_break;

    if (increment < global_mem - p_break  ||  increment >= limit - p_break)
    {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return (void*)-1;
    }
    p_break += increment;

    return original;
}
```

(I moved the global variables into the function to reduce their scope; that might not be appropriate if you also want to implement `brk()`, but I'm only reviewing the code I see!)

Comment: Question - Could there be any resulting bad effects of those 2 overflows occurring that you mentioned? As far as I knew, say that the math ends up overflowing, I'm never actually storing or accessing that overflowed address so was just curious if there was some other bad side effect of overflowing in the math even without an access or storage of the overflowed memory address?

Thank you for your thorough and helpful answer

Comment: @the_endian The code inside the `if`s might or might not get executed when it shouldn't/should.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic overflow results in Undefined Behaviour, so absolutely anything is a possible outcome.  Following the wrong branch of the conditional is the *least bad* outcome!